# better alternative to C# contains method

Tags: c#, list, contains

Is there a faster alternative to using the Contains method in C#?

Here is a sample that looks like what I'm trying to do, but I have read that Contains is an expensive way to do it and I want to find a better alternative as speed is important.

```
    public List<Guid> getCumulativeListByUsername(string username)
    {
        List<Guid> CombinedList = new List<Guid>();
        List<Guid> ListA = new List<Guid>();
        List<Guid> ListB = new List<Guid>();

        ListA = getListAFromDatabase(username);
        ListB = getListBFromDatabase(username);

        CombinedList = ListA;

        foreach (Guid x in ListB)
        {
            if (!CombinedList.Contains(x))
            {
                CombinedList.Add(x);
            }
        }
        return CombinedList;
    }
```

If you could explain your reasoning as well, it would be appreciated.

Comment: _"I have read that Contains is an expensive way to do it"_ - do you notice that in practice? And where did you read that, did they offer alternatives? If not, what did your research show? The de facto answer to this is to use a HashSet or Dictionary, I'm sure you must have read that as well?

Comment: Are you encountering any actual performance problems?

Comment: If you are pulling 2 lists from a database perhaps combine there, databases are good at set operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823860/c-listt-contains-too-slow

Comment: Why not `Intersect`?

Comment: I searched for answer before I posted, not sure why I didn't find the ones you did.  Anyways I only came here to learn @CodeCaster thanks for the downvote though. smh.

Comment: Don't take it personal. :) Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about performance, you'd need to provide details on list length, likely hood of a clash, etc. But you can shorten the code with Linq:

```
return ListA.Union(ListB).ToList();
```

I'd want to prove a performance problem exists before trying to arbitrarily improve performance and more than likely making the code less readable.

Comment: voteup, But you no need Distinct there, Union do it inside

Comment: Most of the time Linq is slower that direct iteration.

Comment: @CodeCaster, cause it more faster readable and short solution than in answer

Comment: @gabba that's not what the question asked for.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Contains in list take o(n), Union uses hashes inside so it o(1)

Comment: @CodeCaster, I've read question again but still didn't see difference. Sorry for that

Comment: @gabba the question is asking for faster execution (fewer CPU cycles used in execution), not faster readability (fewer lines of code).

Comment: @CodeCaster, this solution faster than scan in loop