# Why List<T>.Contains() is too slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a list of objects and I want to filter the list by removing some objects that have `ids` present in a separate list i.e.

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles;  //All Vehicles List (260 vehicles data)
List<int> vehiclesIds;  //Ids List to remove from Original List (Length < 260)
```

Now for removing if i'm using `RemoveAll()` it takes areound `25 to 30 seconds`.

```
vehicles.RemoveAll(e => vehiclesIds.Contains(e.Id));
```

But if I'm using `for loop` as the following it takes only `8 to 20 milliseconds`.

```
foreach (var vehiclesId in vehiclesIds)
{
    vehicles.RemoveAll(e=> vehiclesId == e.Id);
}
```

I multiple times run this code and analyse this after using `StopWatch` that `List.Contains()` is the reason for slow processing.

Comment: If this is all in memory and your lists are just a few hundred items, 25 to 30 seconds seems insanely high.  Pretty curious what's going on there.

Comment: Why is this tagged `entity-framework`? I could see some explanation for the slowness if the `List`s you mention aren't actually lists, but entity sets or queries (as that could mean database queries are happening for every lookup). If they are both plain lists, though, there's no way the former would be much slower than the latter, especially not to the tune of 25 seconds -- I'd need a [mre] before I'd believe that.

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823860/listt-contains-is-very-slow. Hope it helps.

Comment: Misspelling of `Vehcle` suggests this is not real. Are we really talking about lists?

Comment: Is `vehiclesId` in the real code actually a property which is computed every time it's accessed?

Comment: Can you please try `var ids = vehiclesIds.ToList(); vehicles.RemoveAll(e => ids.Contains(e.Id));`? (I'm assuming that in your real code vehiclesIds is not a local variable).

Answer (score 3):

The logic between these two versions is different.

The first version loops the vehicles first, looking for matches in the IDs. `Contains` uses the default comparer, which might be a slow way of comparing because it uses interfaces.

You can improve this version by using a `HashSet<int>` to find matching IDs. This should be faster (even though it also uses `Contains`) as it uses a hashtable internally.

```cs
List<Vehicle> vehicles;  //All Vehicles List (260 vehicles data)
HashSet<int> vehiclesIds;  //Ids List to remove from Original List (Length < 260)

vehicles.RemoveAll(e => vehiclesIds.Contains(e.Id));
```

The second version instead loops the smaller list of IDs first. You can improve this version by using a `Dictionary` for the `vehicles`

```cs
Dictionary<int, Vehicle> vehicles;  //All Vehicles List (260 vehicles data)
List<int> vehiclesIds;  //Ids List to remove from Original List (Length < 260)

foreach (var vehiclesId in vehiclesIds)
{
    vehicles.Remove(vehiclesId);
}
```

i would imagine this last version to be the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: The answer to your question "Why List.Contains() is too slow?" is: It isn't. There must be something wrong elsewhere that you haven't shown us.

Longer answer:

The first version *should* be faster because it's only removing elements from the list once rather than multiple times. (The fact that it isn't faster points to some problem elsewhere.)

However, the first version does call `vehiclesIds.Contains(e.Id)` once for each vehicle, which is an O(N) operation.

You could improve that by creating a `HashSet<int>` from the vehicle IDs and then use that for the lookup.

I tried the three approaches (your two plus the `HashSet` one) in a benchmark:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Demo;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<UnderTest>();
    }
}

sealed class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UnderTest
{
    public UnderTest()
    {
        var rng = new Random(34655);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IDS; ++i)
            _vehicleIds.Add(rng.Next(0, MAX_ID));

        _idsHash = _vehicleIds.ToHashSet();
    }

    [IterationSetup]
    public void IterationSetup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IterationSetup");
        createVehicleList();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RemoveItemsUsingRemoveAll()
    {
        _vehicles.RemoveAll(e => _vehicleIds.Contains(e.Id));
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RemoveItemsUsingLoop()
    {
        foreach (int vehiclesId in _vehicleIds)
        {
            _vehicles.RemoveAll(e => vehiclesId == e.Id);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RemoveItemsUsingHashSet()
    {
        _vehicles.RemoveAll(e => _idsHash.Contains(e.Id));
    }

    void createVehicleList()
    {
        _vehicles.Clear();
        var rng = new Random(78712);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VEHICLES; ++i)
        {
            _vehicles.Add(new Vehicle {Id = rng.Next(MAX_ID)});
        }
    }

    const int NUM_VEHICLES = 200_000;
    const int MAX_ID       = 800_000;
    const int NUM_IDS      =   1_000;

    readonly List<int>     _vehicleIds = new ();
    readonly List<Vehicle> _vehicles   = new ();
    readonly HashSet<int>  _idsHash;
}
```

The results I obtained on my PC were as follows:

```
|                     Method |       Mean |      Error |     StdDev |     Median |
|--------------------------- |-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|
|  RemoveItemsUsingRemoveAll |  68.360 ms |  1.4030 ms |  4.0926 ms |  67.828 ms |
|       RemoveItemsUsingLoop | 625.148 ms | 19.4181 ms | 56.3354 ms | 607.409 ms |
|    RemoveItemsUsingHashSet |   5.293 ms |  0.2643 ms |  0.7626 ms |   5.323 ms |
```

As you can see, using your first version is significantly faster than your second version (as I expected), but using a `HashSet` is even faster.

The conclusion that we must draw is that the slowdown you're seeing is due to code that you haven't shown us.